# Treap Data Structure

Tags: binary-search-tree, heap, complexity-theory, treap

The height of Treap is said to be logarithmic in order.
But while performing an online insertion for given key **(1,2),(1,3),(3,4),(4,5)** in order, the height of the treap is of the order of input.

So the worst case complexity is turning out to be linear.
Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are given:

- The priority of your node ist independent of your data (it is a random number)
- The chance of the worst case you described is 2/(n!) (ascending/descending occurance of random numbers)

So the runtime can be considered (amortized) Log(n) (average runtime with the same (worst case) data).